# How to run code every time page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

In my jQuery Mobile project I have an image slider on the homepage. This works fine when entering via this page. However, if I navigate away, and then return to the page, it doesn't work.

I have 1 html file for each JQM page (eg 4 pages equals 4 html files).

The code JS given below is loaded via a reference in the header of the page to the JS file containing it.

```
$(function () {
    //Global variable that stores advertising banners.
    var featured = new Array();

    //Adds information about the new banners.
    featured.push(["http://www.google.co.uk/", "assets/temp/slider/01.jpg", "FEATURED: Cessna CItation XVII"]);
    featured.push(["http://www.mashable.com", "assets/temp/slider/02.jpg", "FEATURED: Cessna CItation XVII"]);
    featured.push(["http://www.engadget.com", "assets/temp/slider/16.jpg", "FEATURED: Cessna CItation XVII"]);

    var featured_element = document.getElementById("slider");

    //Prints a new link with image in advertising box.
    $.each(featured, function (i, advert) {
        featured_element.innerHTML += "<img src=\"" + advert[1] + "\" data-plugin-slide-caption=\"<a href='" + advert[0] + "'>" + advert[2] + "<\/a>\"/>";
    });

    $("#slider").excoloSlider({
        mouseNav: false,
        interval: 3500, // = 3.5 seconds
        playReverse: true
    });
});
```

How can I adapt this so that it fires every time this given page is loaded?

Comment: `window.onpopstate = function(){...};` ???

Comment: why dont you use document.ready() ?

Comment: @PratikJoshi Because its Jquery Mobile.

Comment: Hi Phill. If you're using _Single Page Model_, custom JS code should be placed inside `data-role="page"`. check this [post](http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/jquery-mobile-page-events/). Let me know if you need more details :) "_jQM Shaolin Master_" ;)

Comment: @Omar, I'm doing that, but still no luck. I'll expand my question a little more in the morning. It's good to see you. ;-)

Comment: Ok Phill, let me know once you have it updated. It's good to see you again too :)

Comment: @Omar, in fact I've actually solved this one. I have a very similar question, and got confused. Ill edit this in the morning and mark up the answer for future reference. I'll also post my other question, which I think will be a bit interesting for you.

Comment: Good to hear so, go ahead and post an answer. Looking forward to solving it ;)

Comment: @Omar, I've popped my solution to this question as an answer here. If you are bored, please take a look and let me how if I'm learning well from you. I'll pop that other question up tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CORRECTION**
Ive actually had to call the js file in the body to get it to work without causing issues with the 2nd page.

---

After a bit of scrambling through past answers from @Omar, and trialing the various JQM events, Ive come up with the following.

I've created a script in a js file and reference this in the head of the default.html. This will be turned into a PhoneGap app, so I know this will be the first page hit.

In the JS file I've updated the code to:

```
$(document).one("pageshow", function () {
alert("LOADED SLIDER CODE");
//Global variable that stores advertising banners.
var featured = new Array();

  //Adds information about the new banners.
  featured.push(["http://www.google.co.uk/", "assets/temp/slider/01.jpg", "FEATURED: Cessna CItation XVII"]);
  featured.push(["http://www.mashable.com", "assets/temp/slider/02.jpg", "FEATURED: Cessna CItation XVII"]);
  featured.push(["http://www.engadget.com", "assets/temp/slider/16.jpg", "FEATURED: Cessna CItation XVII"]);
  /*
  featured.push(["", "", ""]);
  featured.push(["", "", ""]);
  featured.push(["", "", ""]);
  featured.push(["", "", ""]);
  featured.push(["", "", ""]);
  featured.push(["", "", ""]);
  featured.push(["", "", ""]);
  */


  var featured_element = document.getElementById("slider");

  //Prints a new link with image in advertising box.
  $.each(featured, function(i, advert) {
        featured_element.innerHTML += "<img src=\""+advert[1]+"\" data-plugin-slide-caption=\"<a href='"+advert[0]+"'>"+advert[2]+"<\/a>\"/>";
  });

    $("#slider").excoloSlider({
        mouseNav: false,
        interval: 3500, // = 3.5 seconds
        playReverse: true
    });
});
```

Now the js is called whenever the page widgets etc have loaded into the DOM, and essential shows when the 'page' is first shown.

Comment: @Omar, just realised I've added the js reference in the body to get this to work. But that might cause it to load multiple times if the users goes back to the default page more than once? Could that cause issues?? Do you have any ninja skills to improve this? Thanks.

Comment: You're loading the slider on first page only? Since it's first page loaded and you're using `.one()`, the code won't be executed more than one. IF it's not the first page and you're using _Single Page Model_, the code will run each time the page is viewed. However, once you navigate away from that page it will be removed from DOM, so no worries I assume.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your gallery code inside pagecreate blinded function.

```
jQuery( ".selector" ).on( "pagecreate", function( event ) {
  //Gallery code here
})
```

Here `.selector` is the page that you put the jQuery-Mobile page.

Comment: I tried that from the docs, but it doesn't fire at all. Using the following code for a page with its page id="homepage" $("#homepage").on( "pagecreate", function( event )

Comment: Just so you know, it wasn't me who down voted. You should be made to give a public statement of 'why' whenever you try to downvote someone.

Comment: You have to practice "formatting" code in your answers.

Comment: @PhillHealey it is, why not making it look better when it's possible?

Comment: @Omar, true, but its a bit harsh to downvote isnt it? Hes trying to help, after all. Maybe he didnt have much time or perhaps he was typing the answer on his phone. Id rather someone try to help and not format it, than not bother. OR answer in two weeks but have a perfectly laid out post. ;-)

Comment: @Omar, not sure if youll get my comment on my answer. I just had to update it. Could you take a look, please?

Comment: Oh I didn't see this, I'll try to format code next time..I know how much we have to suffer when we are having a problem. That's why I try to answer quickly as possible so someone will stop bumping their heads on blind walls..